# how can I do a data type recursive in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

How I can do a data type like this:

```
data Xpto = String [Xpto ]

insertHead :: String -> Xpto 
insertHead s = s []
```

I got this message:

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : s []
*** Term           : s
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : a -> b
```

Comment: a type always starts with uppercase.

Comment: Done. It does not resolve my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that the data type is recursive. You can not define lowercase data types. Types start with an **uppercase**.

Furthermore your have to **define a constructor**, the most straightforward constructor here is probably `Xpto` as well (constructors also start with an upercase).

So by writing:

```
data Xpto = Xpto String [Xpto]
--          ^ constructor

insertHead :: String -> Xpto
insertHead s = Xpto s []
--             ^ apply the data constructor
```

Or we can make `insertHead` pointfree, by using `flip`:

```
insertHead :: String -> Xpto
insertHead = flip Xpto []
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But How can I access to list?

function2 p d (insertHead x xs) = notElem p xs <- My problem is acess to xs

Comment: Sounds like a separate question.  Also notice there are no arrays discussed here, just linked lists.

Comment: You're rigth @Thomas M. DuBuisson

Comment: @JoaoRafael `[Int]` is *not* an array, it is a *(linked) list*. You can for instance access the `i`-th element with `a!!i`, but this is usually a sign that something is wrong with the algorithm, since Haskell aims to construct algorithms that *iterate* over lists, not *random access* it.